# Javascript / Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is the code that I made that has worked but all of a sudden stopped working:

```
var waitEqua = 1 * 1 * 1000;

function getTC() {
    $.get (
        'http://www.roblox.com/marketplace/tradecurrency.aspx',

        function parseData(data) {
            var stuff = $(data).find('.CurrencyQuote');
            var rowh = stuff.find('.TableRow');
            var rate = rowh.find('.Rate');
            var rateb = /(......)(.)(......)/(rate.text());
            var spread = rowh.find('.Spread').text();
            localStorage["Tix"] = rateb[1];
            localStorage["Robux"] = rateb[3];
            localStorage["Spread"] = spread;
            spreadTehToast(spread);
        }
    );
}
```

My error is at `var rateb = /(......)(.)(......)/(rate.text());` with the error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function.  I have not changed the code.  It has just broke.

Comment: The same is true for Firefox. /regex/(arg) used to work in the past but after a recent "security update", it stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rateb = /(......)(.)(......)/(rate.text());
```

is not valid JS to the best of my knowledge (the RegEx is not a function but an object as the error suggests, yet you're trying to use it as a function), it looks like a call to `exec()` has gone missing. Try this:

```
var rateb = /(......)(.)(......)/.exec(rate.text());
```

Comment: @Jopc67: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask